# linux + adding swap space

Tags: linux, redhat, lvm, swap

I performed the following procedure in order to add **400m** to swap,

I took the **400m** from the sdb disk for the swap increasing

Everything was ok but before the last command , I performed

```
mkswap /dev/rootvg/swap
```

And I get the following warning messages from mkswap

```
mkswap: /dev/rootvg/swap: warning: don't erase bootbits sectors
    on whole disk. Use -f to force.
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 2490364 KiB
no label, UUID=2f42fa37-987d-40a5-8cf6-5707e1d8f077
```

Finally swap was extend to **2.4G as expected**

But I little worry about the warning message from mkswap command

Please advise what is meaning of the warning:

```
mkswap: /dev/rootvg/swap: warning: don't erase bootbits sectors
on whole disk. Use -f to force.
```

And if this is OK?

My procedure on the linux redhat machine - version 6

```
# swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used      Priority
/dev/dm-1                               partition       2064380 0       -1

# free
        total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       5991892     539036    5452856        212      70444     270664
-/+ buffers/cache:     197928    5793964
 Swap:      2064380          0    2064380


# pvs
PV         VG      Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
 /dev/sdb   rootvg  lvm2 a--u  7.97g 416.00m
 /dev/sdc   orahome lvm2 a--u 30.00g  15.00g

# lsblk /dev/sdb
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb                     8:16   0    8G  0 disk
|-rootvg-swap (dm-1)  253:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
|-rootvg-slash (dm-2) 253:2    0  576M  0 lvm  /
|-rootvg-usr (dm-3)   253:3    0  1.4G  0 lvm  /usr
|-rootvg-home (dm-4)  253:4    0  256M  0 lvm  /home
|-rootvg-opt (dm-5)   253:5    0  416M  0 lvm  /opt
`-rootvg-var (dm-6)   253:6    0    3G  0 lvm  /var

# swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used     Priority
/dev/dm-1                               partition       2064380 0       -1

# swapoff /dev/rootvg/swap

# lvresize /dev/rootvg/swap -L +400m
 Rounding size to boundary between physical extents: 416.00 MiB.
 Size of logical volume rootvg/swap changed from 1.97 GiB (63 extents) to  2.38 GiB (76 extents).
 Logical volume swap successfully resized.

# mkswap /dev/rootvg/swap
mkswap: /dev/rootvg/swap: warning: don't erase bootbits sectors
    on whole disk. Use -f to force.
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 2490364 KiB
no label, UUID=2f42fa37-987d-40a5-8cf6-5707e1d8f077

# swapon /dev/rootvg/swap

# free
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
 Mem:       5991892     539680    5452212        212      70536     270892
 -/+ buffers/cache:     198252    5793640
 Swap:      2490364          0    2490364
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a safety precaution to prevent you from destroying a boot sector, etc... when using a whole disk when you may have meant to use a partition.

This warning message not longer present in CentOS 6.5 nor Ubuntu 16.04.

This older (2006) `mkswap.c` defines bootbits vaguely: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/busybox/util-linux/mkswap.c

```
/*  char     bootbits[1024];    Space for disklabel etc. */
```

From the CentOS 6.5 `mkswap.c`:

```
        if (is_whole_disk_fd(fd, devname)) {
                /* don't zap bootbits on whole disk -- we know nothing
                 * about bootloaders on the device */
                whole = 1;
                zap = 0;
```

I'm not amazing with C, but the new code appears more intelligent and perhaps preserves boot data. I'm not delving that far.

Comment: by the way I this machine is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)

Comment: so the button  line is not use the -f option , ?  ,

Comment: @Jogeff I downloaded the code for Centos 6.5 util-linux-ng-2.17.2 and that error message is not in the code. Perhaps RHEL is different, or the newer one is... I did the same for Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @Jogeff There's nothing wrong with zapping (as the code calls it) an LVM volume you created for swap as far as I'm concerned, unless you boot off it? Using -f is fine.

Comment: @Jogeff There are many many references on google search for that error. People override with -f all the time when using whole disks.

Comment: yes I know - but I got lost , and not exactly know if this is a problem or not

Comment: @Jogeff What are you concerned about? I answered your question in detail.

Comment: ok thank you , so now I am more relax about it , I also rebooted the machine and evrything is OK